# Display each row from MySQL in a separate DIV

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a posts table which contains a field for the posts. Let's say I have 10 posts that i want to show in 10 divs. How should I proceed in doing that? I've managed to get the full contents using a while loop, but that only shows the full contents in one place, and I want to have individual divs (so i can use different background colors) for each individual post.

Help me out please, I hope it makes sense. Just think at the way facebook displays posts for example. Each post has it's own box. I want something similar.

Snippet of the code I have to get the posts is available here:

```
<?php
require_once("includes/database.php"); // Get the database connection

$get_post = "SELECT full_post FROM posts";
$show_post = mysqli_query($connection, $get_post);

if (!$show_post) {
echo "Could not load post. " . "(" . mysqli_error($connection) . ")";
}
while ($post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show_post)) {
echo $post["full_post"] . "<br />";
}
mysqli_free_result($show_post);

?>
```

Comment: show some code please

Comment: show us your code, so we can make it work as you desire.

Comment: Code sample or it didn't happen.

Comment: code sample added in the first post. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method of doing this is creating the divs from the `while` function that's showing your posts and adding CSS classes to them.

Example:

```
while ($post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show_post)) {
echo '<div class="blue">';
echo $post["full_post"] . "<br />";
echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Multumesc, e aproape ceea ce cautam

Comment: e ok, doar ca e mai util cel de sus, pentru ca nu vreau sa incrementez nimic. Loopul while se duce pana nu mai gaseste nimic. Singura chestie care nu stiam s-o fac e sa il includ intr-un div.

Comment: L-am editat, nu-ti vazusem codul initial si nu stiam exact cum faci.

Comment: E perfect. Cum pot sa te mai deranjez cu cateva intrebari ? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41776/discussion-between-alex-dumitru-and-popa-andrei)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are looping through the individual posts using the while-loop. You can start a new div every round.

```
while($post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print '<div>';
    print $post->content;
    print '</div>';
}
```

Comment: No, don't mix `mysql_*` functions with MySQLi.

Comment: I know that's deprecated. Haven't even saw it said mysql_ I instinctively went on using mysqli_ instead.